# Overriding a vendor class in Laravel 5.6 not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, oop, multi-tenant

I'm working with Laravel 5.6 and trying to override a class from the hyn/multi-tenant package, but my override doesn't seems to be taking effect. I have detailed my steps below and i'm hoping for some guidance on what i might be missing or doing incorrectly.

I have followed this solution:
[Other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841930/laravel-6-7-how-can-i-override-change-a-vendor-class)

The file i'm attempting to override:
`vendor/hyn/multi-tenant/src/Generators/Webserver/Database/Drivers/MariaDB.php`

My custom file:
`app/Overrides/CustomMariaDB.php`

In my AppServiceProvider i have the following code:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(
        'Hyn\Tenancy\Generators\Webserver\Database\Drivers\MariaDB',
        CustomMariaDB::class
    );
}
```

and in my composer.json, under the autoload section, i have included these:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "vendor/hyn/multi-tenant/src/Generators/Webserver/Database/Drivers/MariaDB.php"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php",
        "app/Overrides/CustomMariaDB.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

The vendor mariaDB.php file looks like this.

```
namespace Hyn\Tenancy\Generators\Webserver\Database\Drivers;

use Hyn\Tenancy\Contracts\Webserver\DatabaseGenerator;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Database\Connection;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Events\Websites\Created;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Events\Websites\Deleted;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Events\Websites\Updated;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Exceptions\GeneratorFailedException;
use Illuminate\Database\Connection as IlluminateConnection;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

    class MariaDB implements DatabaseGenerator
    {
        /**
         * @param Created $event
         * @param array $config
         * @param Connection $connection
         * @return bool
         */
        public function created(Created $event, array $config, Connection $connection): bool
        {
            $create = function ($connection) use ($config) {
                return $connection->statement("CREATE DATABASE `{$config['database']}`");
            };
            $grant = function ($connection) use ($config) {
                return $connection->statement("GRANT ALL ON `{$config['database']}`.* TO `{$config['username']}`@'{$config['host']}' IDENTIFIED BY '{$config['password']}'");
            };
    
            return $connection->system()->transaction(function (IlluminateConnection $connection) use ($create, $grant) {
                return $create($connection) && $grant($connection);
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * @param Updated $event
         * @param array $config
         * @param Connection $connection
         * @return bool
         * @throws GeneratorFailedException
         */
        public function updated(Updated $event, array $config, Connection $connection): bool
        {
            $uuid = Arr::get($event->dirty, 'uuid');
    
            $this->created(new Created($event->website), $config, $connection);
    
    //        if (!$connection->system()->statement("RENAME TABLE `$uuid`.`table` TO `{$config['database']}`.`table`")) {
    //            throw new GeneratorFailedException("Could not rename database {$config['database']}, the statement failed.");
    //        }
    
            return true;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param Deleted $event
         * @param array $config
         * @param Connection $connection
         * @return bool
         * @throws GeneratorFailedException
         */
        public function deleted(Deleted $event, array $config, Connection $connection): bool
        {
            if (!$connection->system()->statement("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `{$config['database']}`")) {
                throw new GeneratorFailedException("Could not delete database {$config['database']}, the statement failed.");
            }
    
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then I copied and edited the mariaDB.php as CustomMariaDB file to folder "app\Overrides".

```
namespace App\Overrides;

use Hyn\Tenancy\Generators\Webserver\Database\Drivers\MariaDB as BaseMariaDB;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Contracts\Webserver\DatabaseGenerator;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Database\Connection;
use Hyn\Tenancy\Events\Websites\Created;
use Illuminate\Database\Connection as IlluminateConnection;

class CustomMariaDB extends BaseMariaDB {
    public function created(Created $event, array $config, Connection $connection): bool
    {
        $create = function ($connection) use ($config) {
            return $connection->statement("CREATE DATABASE `{$config['database']}`");
        };
        $createUser = function ($connection) use ($config) {
            return $connection->statement("CREATE USER `{$config['username']}`@'{$config['host']}' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '{$config['password']}'");
        };
        $grant = function ($connection) use ($config) {
            return $connection->statement("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `{$config['database']}`.* TO `{$config['username']}`@'{$config['host']}'");
        };

        return $connection->system()->transaction(function (IlluminateConnection $connection) use ($create, $createUser, $grant) {
            return $create($connection) && $createUser($connection) && $grant($connection);
        });
    }

}
```

after making these changes i have run composer dump-autoload as well and clear cache.
However my customMariaDb class doesn't seems to be overriding the main mariaDb class from the package. I have checked the namespace and class deceleration ensured that my custom class extends the original class.

Are there any additional steps or considerations i might be missing to successfully override a vendor class in Laravel 5.6?

Any insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... why are you assuming that would do anything at all?  that package doesn't use the IoC to resolve the driver, it manually creates an instance `return new $drivers[$driver]();`

Comment: @lagbox Given this new information, could you suggest an alternative method to override or extend the functionality of the MariaDB driver in this package? Is there a way to intercept the manual instantiation process or perhaps extend the class where the instance is created?

Answer (score -1):

This information for the drivers is coming from a singleton bound to the container by a Service Provider. The `DatabaseDriverFactory` is manually creating an instance of the database driver and not using the IoC to resolve them. You could **attempt** to override this Collection with your class for the 'mysql' key:

```
$drivers = this->app['tenancy.db.drivers'] ?? [];
$drivers['mysql'] = YourMariaDBClass::class;
$this->app->singleton('tenancy.db.drivers', function () use ($drivers) {
    return $drivers;
});
```

You could add this to the `boot` method of a Service Provider.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i'm using hyn package v 5.1 i'm getting null for $this->app('tenancy.db.drivers');

Comment: you are getting `null` for that when calling it where?

Comment: in appServiceProvider boot method

Comment: updated ... but this is also a timing thing

Comment: i have edit my question, include some code please check and tell where i'm wrong.

Comment: updated ... there is a `DatabaseDriverFactory` class that creates the drivers and it pulls the list of drivers from that binding on the container ... https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant/blob/5.x/src/Generators/Webserver/Database/DatabaseDriverFactory.php#L24