# Overwriting (AuthO) Vendor package functionality in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vendor

In this file, I would like to overwrite some functionality of the one function in that file:
[AuthO Laravel Package](https://github.com/auth0/laravel-auth0/blob/main/src/Controllers/CallbackControllerAbstract.php)

The package is installed as a Vendor package in the application.

I dont want to change any route functionality in the application, and I dont want to fork the package.

The above file/function runs on a callback from AuthO. All this works fine, and I run `\Log::info()` from the file to check that it runs the code. Assume this works as intended in the Vendor package.

I have the following custom provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\AuthOService;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomAuthOServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
  public function register(): void
  {
    // Bind the custom controller to the original controller
    $this->app->bind(\Auth0\Login\Controllers\CallbackControllerAbstract::class, AuthOService::class);
  }
}
```

This is registered is config\app :

```
..
        'providers' => [
            App\Providers\CustomAuthOServiceProvider::class,
        ]
...
```

Then I have a service class in App\Services:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Vendor\Auth0\Login\Controllers\CallbackControllerAbstract;
// use Auth0\Login\Controllers\CallbackControllerAbstract;

class AuthOService extends CallbackControllerAbstract
{
    /**
     * Handle the callback from the identity provider.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request): Response
    {
        \Log::info('Handling provider callback. test');

        // Change the redirection URL to '/testtest'
        return redirect('/testtest')->intended('/');
    }
}
```

With all the code implementations above, there are no errors when the application runs.

But the `function __invoke` is not running, and the `\Log` is not hit in my `AuthOService.php`.

I have checked the following:

[Overwrite Laravel vendor package](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/override-a-service-used-in-vendor-package)

[Best way to override a class inside a vendor package?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/best-way-to-override-a-class-inside-a-vendor-package)

[How Can I Override/Change a Vendor Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841930/laravel-6-7-how-can-i-override-change-a-vendor-class)

The above links have helped me to be at the current stage of where I am at, but now I am stuck and dont know what to do from here.

**How do I overwrite/extend on the specific file mentioned at the top, in a Laravel Application, without forking or changing routes?**

What I specifically want to change/overwrite is the exception on line 105:

```
$exception = new CallbackControllerException(sprintf(CallbackControllerException::MSG_API_RESPONSE, $error, $errorDescription));
```